# CSV to directory

Tags: python, csv

I have CSV file which contains information about
     Car and Email

```
BMW, person1@mail.com
Mercedes, person2@mail.com
Dodge, person1@mail.com
```

etc.

I'm trying to do the script which makes a dictionary from CSV where email is key and a car is value. Every key can have more values.

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open('report.csv'))

output = {}
for row in reader:
key = row[1]
value = row[0]
if key in output:
    if row[0] == output.get(key):
        pass
    else:
        output[key].append(value)
output[key] = value

print(output)
```

for every row, I'm trying to check if is the car(value) already value of email(key). If is then pass to next row, if not then add value to the key.

Output should looks like

```
{'person1@mail.com': ['BMW', 'Dodge'],'person2@mail.com': ['Mercedes']}
```

but after compilating error `'str' object has no attribute 'append'` comes up

Thank you

Comment: Think about the text of the error, what object you're trying to append to, and how you created that object.

Comment: I guess you know what `output[key]` is, it's not a list.

Comment: HINT: is your dictionary value a string or array? What should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, You are trying to append a string to a string in `output[key].append(value)`. where `output[key]` is itself a string.

Use list to add `value` as `[value]`, so that you can append.

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open('report.csv'))

output = {}
for row in reader:
    key = row[1]
    value = row[0]
    print key, value

    if key not in output:
        output[key] = [value]

    else:
        output[key].append(value)

print(output)

# output
# {' person2@mail.com': ['Mercedes'], ' person1@mail.com': ['BMW', 'Dodge']}
```

Comment: Working! Thank you for hint :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the [collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) module you can use the `defaultdict` object to achieve the output that you need

```
import csv 
from collections import defaultdict

d =defaultdict(list)

with open("t.csv","rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        d[line[1]].append(line[0])
```

outputs:

```
d

defaultdict(list,
            {' person1@mail.com': ['BMW', 'Dodge'],
             ' person2@mail.com': ['Mercedes']})
```